# How to set and clean interval by toggle function in react with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, react-hooks, clearinterval

I'm trying to build a timer witch is triggered by one button with function *handleToggle*, which looks like:

```
const handleToggle = () => {
    let timer = () => setInterval(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "COUNT", payload: Date.now() - startTime });
    }, 100);
    const startTime = Date.now() - AppState.runningTime;
    if (AppState.countingStarted) {
      dispatch({
        type: "COUNTING_STARTED",
        payload: false
      });
      clearInterval(timer());
    } else {
      timer()
      dispatch({ type: "COUNTING_STARTED", payload: true });
    }
  };
```

*COUNTING_STARTED* is a dispatch function which toggles *AppState.countingStarted*.

I'm struggling with stopping a timer, how to clear that timer-Interval?
I tried:

```
const handleToggle = () => {
    let timer;
    if (AppState.countingStarted) {
      dispatch({
        type: "COUNTING_STARTED",
        payload: false
      });
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "COUNT", payload: Date.now() - startTime });
      }, 100);
      const startTime = Date.now() - AppState.runningTime;
      dispatch({ type: "COUNTING_STARTED", payload: true });
    }
  };
```

but there is no difference...

Comment: You initialized the timer again in the `handleToggle` again

Comment: You might check out Dan Abramov's blogpost on using `setInterval` with hooks: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the reference to the `intervalId` is lost at the end of the function execution.

You should use an instance variable to store the intervalId. If you have a `Class` component you can use the following code :

```
handleToggle = () => {
  // clear the interval, no matter the value of AppState.countingStarted
  // this prevent from recreating the interval multiple times
  clearInterval(this.timerId);

  if (AppState.countingStarted) {
     dispatch({type: "COUNTING_STARTED",payload: false});   
  } else {
    // store the timer id in an instance variable
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "COUNT", payload: Date.now() - startTime });
    }, 100);

    dispatch({ type: "COUNTING_STARTED", payload: true });
}
```

If you are in a `Function` component, you can use the [hook useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) to get the same behavior :

```
const timerIdRef = useRef(null);

const handleToggle = () => {
  clearInterval(timerIdRef.current);

  if (AppState.countingStarted) {
     dispatch({type: "COUNTING_STARTED",payload: false});   
  } else {
    // store the interval id into the current property
    timerIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "COUNT", payload: Date.now() - startTime });
    }, 100);

    dispatch({ type: "COUNTING_STARTED", payload: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: what you pass to `clearInterval` has to be the return value from `setInterval`; in the first example you are passing your own function to it. The second example has this right, but you're storing the `timer` (the result of calling `setInterval`) in the scope of the toggle function, which means once the function completes, you lose the reference to it; the next time you call the function (e.g. to stop it), you re-define `timer`, which is not what you want.

All you need is to keep the `timer` variable in a scope where it will persist. For example:

```
let timer = null;

const handleToggle = () => {
  if (AppState.countingStarted) {
    dispatch({
      type: "COUNTING_STARTED",
      payload: false
    });
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "COUNT", payload: Date.now() - startTime });
    }, 100);
    const startTime = Date.now() - AppState.runningTime;
    dispatch({ type: "COUNTING_STARTED", payload: true });
  }
};
```

This function can be called multiple times; the `timer` variable will persist throughout.